# If $R$ is a Boolean ring, then $R[x]$ is a coherent ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a (commutative) boolean ring with unity. That is, we have $a=a^2$ for every $a \in R$.

The ring $R$ is called the coherent ring if and only if every finitely generated ideal is finitely presented ideal.

I have a question that if $R$ is boolean, then is $R[x]$ coherent?

I find the result about the power series ring $R[[x]]$ in [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81983328.pdf).

Then, how about $R[x]$?

In coherent ring, we have that the intersection of two finitely generated ideal is also finitely generated. Therefore, if we can show that $R[x]$ is coherent for a boolean ring $R$, every the finite intersection of finitely generated ideal is finitely generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is coherent whenever $R$ is von Neumann Regular.

See [Coherence of Polynomial Rings](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-054-01/S0002-9939-1976-0417164-2/S0002-9939-1976-0417164-2.pdf)

(The paper also shows much stronger results for $R$ semi-hereditary or of global dimension $2$)

Comment: On the off-chance it needs saying: boolean rings are von Neumann regular, so that's why this applies.  Interesting paper by the way!

Comment: It is! I recommend Vasconcelos' book on rings of global dimension 2. I find the classification of these rings to be a nice mix of remarkable and easy to understand.